# how to get values from dynamic inputs in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a text that depends on a dropdown list.If I check 1 element I will see a text field. if i check 2 i will have 2 input  ... 
the drop-down list is dynamic and I do not know the number of its members each time.
 so can you help me get the input values ​​and associates to the id values ​​from the drop-down list because they are linked and put them in a list that contains the id and value of the input and thanks.

```
//this is the dropdown
<ng-multiselect-dropdown [data]="serviceModalite.list" 
    name="modaliteDemande"
    [settings]="dropdownSettingsModalite"
    [(ngModel)]="selectedItemsModalite"
    (onSelect)="onItemSelectModalite($event)" 
    (onDeSelect)="OnItemDeSelectModalite($event)"
    (onSelectAll)="onSelectAllModalite($event)"
    (onDeSelectAll)="onDeSelectAllModalite($event)"> 
</ng-multiselect-dropdown>



//this is the dynamic input that i want to put its values in a list
<div *ngFor="let M of selectedItemsModalite">
      <label>Tarif {{M.NameModalite}}</label>
      <input placeholder="price">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For dynamic form items, you'll need a `FormArray` field in your `FormGroup` definition. Check out [this article](https://alligator.io/angular/reactive-forms-formarray-dynamic-fields/).

Define your form:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.orderForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    customerName: '',
    email: '',
    items: this.formBuilder.array([])
  });
}
```

Use `formArrayName` and `formGroupName` to work with the dynamic form entries. Most of the time, the `index` will be your group name. Use `formControlName` to simply bind to a name.

```
<div formArrayName="items"
  *ngFor="let item of orderForm.get('items').controls; let i = index;">
  <div [formGroupName]="i">
    <input formControlName="name" placeholder="Item name">
    <input formControlName="description" placeholder="Item description">
    <input formControlName="price" placeholder="Item price">
  </div>

  Chosen name: {{ orderForm.controls.items.controls[i].controls.name.value }}
</div>
```

Whenever any of the dynamic form items change, update your form definition as well.

```
createItem(): FormGroup {
  return this.formBuilder.group({
    name: '',
    description: '',
    price: ''
  });
}

addItem(): void {
  this.items = this.orderForm.get('items') as FormArray;
  this.items.push(this.createItem());
}
```